# Preposition "to" after the verb "Dream" followed by another verb (doing something)

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I was trying to find out if a preposition **to**  after the verb **dream** is correct, as in this example:

> Why do they all dream to come here?

The person who said that in her YT vlog is not a native English speaker.
I understand what prepositions to use with the word **dream** as a noun-  dream of/about(somebody/someone), but the preposition **to** after the verb **dream** doesn't sound correct.
Google search brings results for **dream** (as a noun) **to come**, as well as sentences for **dream** (as a verb) **to come**, but the latter examples have  either foreign sources, or from the social media.
In Oxford examples of sentences with the verb **dream** followed by another verb (doing something) prepositions **of** or **about** are used:

> She dreams of running her own business. (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dream_2)

Should I assume that the sentences where a preposition **to** follows the verb **dream** are grammatically incorrect and the action verb (doing something) must have the **ing** form: "I dream of runn**ing** a marathon." "I dream about visit**ing** Antarctica."

Comment: The verb "dream" can be followed by a that-clause, "of" or "about".  "To" would be wrong as a preposition, but I agree that it sounds wrong as an infinitive particle too.

Comment: Use a gerund. The idiom is _dream of coming/going/winning ..._

Comment: You could say "It was my dream to circumnavigate the world", but that's the only context I can think of for using *dream to*.

Comment: The best way to find out whether to use an infinitive or a gerund is to look in a good dicationary, such as Cambridge Dictionary.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dream  In this case it clearly indicates that the gerund form **of xxxing** is sanctioned, but the **to xxxx** form is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full infinitive, you can certainly say, "Humans dream to maintain the health of their brains." (That has the "in order to" meaning.)

You could also use "to" as a preposition if it's licensed for some other reason. (E.g., a sleep researcher might say, "Every night, the subject has dreamless sleep from 10:00 pm to midnight, dreams to 2:00 am, and then has more dreamless sleep until waking up.") I think that such cases would be rare.

In general, however, you're correct; in English the verb "dream" usually doesn't take a full infinitive dependent (complement). When people say things like what your YT vlogger said, it is often considered unusual or simply incorrect.

Comment: It's not really "in order to." You don't generate the dream as a means of achieving the goal. It seems more like a synonym of "wish."

Comment: @alphabet Why do humans dream? In order to maintain the health of their brains. "Humans" refers not to individual persons but to all members of the species.